# What is the difference between 'next to' and 'by'?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, expression-choice, prepositional-phrases

> There was a table **by** the window.
>     / There was a table **next to** the window.
>
> They live **by** the lake. / They live **next to** the lake.

When should you use **by** and when n**ext to**? Why?

Comment: I thought maybe the choice was to do with the closeness of two things of the same nature, as in 'the house next to mine', two houses, as opposed to the closeness of  two things of a different nature, as in 'I have got a house by the lake,' a house and a lake... Fine, but then, there is a phrase like 'side by side'!

Comment: I would say that you have more leeway with "by"; it's more context sensitive than "next to". A table can be by a door without being next to it. "Next to" seems to imply strict adjacency *along some contextually determined vector or line.* "By" on the other hand just implies *3-dimensional nearness*.

Answer (score 3):

Both the OP's examples with *table* and *window* are acceptable and common, they have very very similar meanings

> There was a table **by** the window

and

> There was a table **next to** the window

I wouldn't know which one to choose, perhaps *by* has a more formal feel.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by) say

> ### by
>
> **5.** Indicating location of a physical object beside a place or object.
>
> - ‘remains were discovered by the roadside’
> - ‘the pram was by the dresser’
>
> SYNONYMS
>     **next to**, beside, next door to, alongside, at the side of, by the side of, abreast of, adjacent to, cheek by jowl with, side by side with
>     **near**, close to, hard by, nearest to, neighbouring, adjoining, abutting, bordering, overlooking

However, just the other day I was making flashcards for a group of private students, and in one of the cards there was a [picture](https://www.google.com/search?sa=G&hl=en-IT&q=Romance&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSlQEJLkjLLOhedbQaiQELEKjU2AQaAggVDAsQsIynCBpiCmAIAxIougqgHMEWuhbaCsUWkhXMC8YW1QrxLK0l8CzzLJov9yubL-4s7CzmLBownXsNI2XboqJjOTsxRppgwRASaCdKaKexDSPrtoE21PiqYnWYVJKn-lP5qh0nWXWLIAQMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgTbz4RlDA,isz:m&ved=0ahUKEwjgmvneiY7hAhUMsqQKHfsoCGAQ2A4ILCgC&biw=1228&bih=647&dpr=1.1#imgrc=Cx4-5ctAd7qIAM:) of a couple having a romantic picnic very close to the lake.

[image]

I could have written “Romantic picnic *next to* the lake”

Instead, without thinking twice, I labelled it:

> Romantic picnic **by** the lake

If the picture had shown a building e.g., a bungalow, in the vicinity of the **sea**, I'd have probably said

> A bungalow **facing** the sea

OR

> A bungalow **in front of** the sea

OR

> A bungalow **near** the sea

But *not* “a bungalow next to the sea”

When something is “by” a place, it can be in any position, it is not necessarily *beside* or *opposite* that area.

For me, “by” feels closer than  “near” but slightly further than *next to*.

When I Ngrammed “picnic **by** the river/lake/sea”, the following [results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=picnic%20by%20the%20river%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20lake%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20sea&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20river%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20river%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cpicnic%20by%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc1) were yielded. People seem to picnic *by the river* six times more frequently than *by the sea*. (I hope I interpreted that statistic correctly, I'm not good at numbers I'm afraid).

[image]

A lake doesn't normally have "sides" while a river can have two sides. You can only have a picnic on one side of the sea, the one facing it, so maybe that explains, in part, the discrepancy between the results.

However, when I used [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=picnic%20next%20to%20the%20river%2Cpicnic%20next%20to%20the%20lake%2Cpicnic%20next%20to%20the%20sea&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=) to chart the following expressions “picnic **next to** the river/lake/sea”, it turned up blank and said: *No valid ngrams to plot! Ngrams not found: *picnic next to the river*, *picnic next to the lake*, *picnic next to the sea*.

Which suggests that English speaking people do not use "picnic" in conjunction with "next to" if the location is a large undefined body of water. What happens if the body of water has straight lines or a definite shape? According to Google Books, there are some instances of *next to the pool* but compared to *by the pool* the latter form is by far preferred.

[image]

Comment: if they had been sat with their feet in the water (or that close), I would say "next to"

Comment: @WendyG yes, very possibly! But even "sat by the lake with their feet in the water" doesn't sound wrong. Interesting reflection :)