# "Sit at the beach"

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the use of "at the beach". I know there were similar topics, however in none of them I can find whether it is possible to say "sit at the beach". More specifically I want to know whether it is correct in this sentence: "By this time next week, we will be sitting at the beach." To me it sounds more natural to say "on the beach" in this case, but I need a second opinion.

Comment: *At the beach* is more idiomatic than *on the beach*. *On* would normally only be specified if you are talking about the physical sand, or some other *beach* composition, rather than the locale itself. The locale is a location, so *at* is used. For example, ***at*** *the restaurant*, not ***on*** *the restaurant*. (But the use of the definite article also plays a role. If you're talking about a *specific* beach, then *at* is certainly more common; if you're talking about a beach in general, then ***on a*** *beach* might also be used.)

Comment: It's perfectly fine.  There are subtle differences between "at" and "on" (or "in") in such contexts, but there are no hard and fast rules as to which to use in most cases.

Comment: American say 'at the beach' where Brits say 'by the seaside'. Sitting by the sea would be very natural for us.

Comment: In the UK I would say that "sitting _at_ the beach" would imply sitting somewhere very close to the beach, for instance on a promenade, on rocks or in a bar or cafe whereas "sitting _on_ the beach" would imply sitting on the beach itself, even if you were on a chair, lounger or towel.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you: I would also say "sitting **on** the beach". I did a search for `*ing _i* the beach` (words ending in *ing* followed by a preposition followed by "the beach") in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and it has 42 hits for "sitting on the beach" and only 2 hits for "sitting at the beach". In addition, there are several similar expressions shown by this query (e.g. *standing*, *lying*, *lounging*) and they all prefer to be paired with *on* as well.

Comment: I definitely agree with *on* as that's closest to German "an", chiefly inflected "am Strand". For *going to* its "an den Strand" as well, or "zum Strand" (zu related to *to*). However, we don't sit up on the beach (Ger. *auf*, which may translate to *on* in other contexts).

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, it may be somewhat variable, as I would suggests "**by** the shore", instead of "at". *go at it* means *against*. This may differ for various dialects, e.g. if influenced by Spanish or French *a*, "vamos *a la* playa (o-oh-oho)".

Comment: My Spanish is very rudimentary but doesn't "Vamos a la playa" mean "go _to_ the beach" not "on the beach", "at the beach" or "by the beach".

Comment: Indeed, and it seems they would sit "en" the beach, too

Comment: @BoldBen, However French "nous sommes à la plage*, "we are at the beach", does yield results. I'm not sure exactly what it means.

Comment: "We are at the beach" is Br English as well. It just doesn't mean that we are, necessarily _on_ the beach, just that we are in its immediate neighbourhood. See my comment to the OP for suggestions of where.

Comment: refer to https://english.stackexchange.com/a/490383/326936 (difference between *next-to* and *by*).